# Visual basic error message for blank field, password and data retrieval system

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am writing a program in visual basic that, when a user enters their email and password (from a list of email and passwords in a CSV file) it will give them their name, address, password etc. I have successfully achieved this however when I input nothing into the field the program simply enters 5 blank lines, how do I fix this? I need an error message to say that nothing has been input and for it to reject it. How do I do this? My code is below:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Label2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Password.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EmailAddress.Click

End Sub



Private Sub Submit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Submit.Click
    Dim currentRow As String()
    Dim foundmatch As Boolean

    Using parserDetails As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("CSV_File.csv")
        parserDetails.SetDelimiters(",")

        While Not parserDetails.EndOfData
            currentRow = parserDetails.ReadFields()

            If EmailAddress.Text = currentRow(0) And Password.Text = currentRow(1) Then
                Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(currentRow)
                foundmatch = True
            End If

        End While
    End Using

    If Not foundmatch Then
        MsgBox("The email and/or password entered cannot be found or is incorrect.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Invalid Email")
    End If
End Sub




Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Input(p1 As String)
    Throw New NotImplementedException
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd use the `If` construct to check for conditions.  For example...

```
Private Sub Submit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Submit.Click

    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EmailAddress.Text) Then
        MsgBox('Email Address is required!')
        Return
    End If

    ' The rest of your logic

End Sub
```

You can check multiple conditions at once, sequentially, etc.

A couple of notes:

1. (I realize this is just a learning exercise but...) If you can load the file into a database-like structure (`DataTable`?) then you may be able to perform more effective searches than just scanning line-by-line.  (Or if you could use an actual database, even better.)  For small amounts of data it may not be a big deal, but scaling to larger amounts will make a difference.
2. FYI - Storing user passwords in plain text is a ***famously bad idea***.  While you're learning and practicing, it would be good to familiarize yourself with password hashing.  Store the hash of the password (not *encrypted*, *hashed*) and when a user enters their password you hash their input and compare the hashes.  It should be impossible for you or anyone else to be able to recover and see the original password.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to make use of something like this:

```
If(Not String.IsNullOrWhitespace(EmailAddress.Text)) Then
    'put
Else 'null/empty or white space
    Msgbox("You cannot leave the email address empty...")
End If
```

I.e. you could change your while block to this:

```
While Not parserDetails.EndOfData
    currentRow = parserDetails.ReadFields()

    If (Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EmailAddress.Text)) Then
        If EmailAddress.Text = currentRow(0) And Password.Text = currentRow(1) Then
            Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(currentRow)
            foundmatch = True
            Exit While
        End If
    Else 'null/empty or white space
        MsgBox("You cannot leave the email address empty...")
        foundmatch = False
        Exit While
    End If
End While
```

Note the addition of the `Exit While`s, which makes it more efficient because it no longer needs to loop after the correct values are found.

Comment: Thanks, this has solved the issue of the 5 blank lines, however the code calls both error messages now (the message for the empty space and the message for the not found) how do I stop the code calling both error messages on no input?